# ASP.NET MVC ViewModel always null @html.displayfor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When I bind my model using @Html.DisplayFor(), it says that the "value cannot be null or empty".

Did the following

1. I checked that the controller passes a valid model to the view.
2. Made sure that the parameters  have the corresponding {get;set;}.
3. Made an @if(Model != null && Model.Param != "") in the view

Funny thing is that it works in the AdminArea and not in the StoreArea. Both areas are using the same model

Edit:

```
    @using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls
    @using SU.Plugin.Payments.BankDeposit.Models.

    @{
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/Master.cshtml";
     }

    @model OrderPaymentModel
  <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                <h2>Payment Form</h2>
                @if (Model.Status == PaymentStatus.Invalid)
                {
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit payment details", "OrderPayment", new {orderId = Model.OrderId, mode = "edit"})
                }
                <div class=custom-page-box-div>
                    <div class="fieldset">
                        <div class="form-fields">
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <label class="col-md- control-label"> @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BankPaidTo)</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(c => c.BankPaidTo.DisplayName)
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.BankPaidTo.DisplayName)
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TransactionNumber)
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TransactionNumber)
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PaidAmount)
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PaidAmount)
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DatePaidDay)
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8 datepicker-dropdowns">

                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.DateOfTransaction)
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                Deposit Slip
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <img src="@Url.Content(Model.DepositSlipUrl)">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can we see the first ~5 lines of the razor view source?

Comment: please share your code

Comment: are you defining the model in the Controller? Are you passing it to the view?

Comment: the models are created in the controller and passed to the view. btw, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. like magic

Comment: on which property you are getting null error in view?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it.

So I tried to remove the DisplayFor's one by one which each removal causing the next parameter to be highlighted with the error. (except for the one that was actually causing the problem. =>

It was only until i noticed the "contentPath" line in the error message and searched it up when I saw what was really causing my problems.

I don't under stand why it skipped that line (binding errors started from the bottom up). but it's fixed now so.. yey